# "TypeError: GridFsStorage is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

for some reason I keep getting a "TypeError: GridFsStorage is not a constructor" error. I have no idea why its giving me this error since I'm just following the official documentation.

**Storage and upload**

```
conn.once('open', ()=> {
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo)
    gfs.collection('uploads')
})

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: DBURI,
    file: (req, file)=> {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf)=> {
                if(err) {
                    return reject(err)
                }
                const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
                const fileInfor = {
                    filename: filename,
                    bucketName: 'uploads'
                }
                resolve(fileInfo)
            })
        })
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage})
```

**Requirement**

```
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage')
```

**Bug**

```
C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\GridFS\server.js:21
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
                ^

TypeError: GridFsStorage is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gabri\Desktop\GridFS\server.js:21:17)      
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [doc on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-gridfs-storage) shows this:

```
const {GridFsStorage} = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
```

which is the same as:

```
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage').GridFsStorage;
```

Whereas you are using this which is not the same at all:

```
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
```

Comment: I was following [a guide from FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/gridfs-making-file-uploading-to-mongodb/), and [the repository referenced there](https://github.com/tejazz/gridfs-file-storage/) [uses the old approach](https://github.com/tejazz/gridfs-file-storage/blob/master/server/app.js#L9). Watch out for this!

Comment: Thanks, so much useful!

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

`import {GridFsStorage} from 'multer-gridfs-storage'`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when an incompatible version of multer is used. Please downgrade to 1.4.4.

See comments for further information: [Dependency problem using multer and multer-gridfs-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74167128/dependency-problem-using-multer-and-multer-gridfs-storage)